# List of .Net Framework methods mapped to SQL syntax by the Linq to Entities provider?

Tags: linq-to-entities

Where can I find a list of methods that Linq to Entities recognizes and converts to propert SQL when processing expressions?

An example of this would be (in .Net 4) the String.Contains method which gets converted to LIKE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CLR Method to Canonical Function Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx)